# Access tmp directory in iOS 8 with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios8, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tmp

Does anyone know how to get the path to the [`tmp` directory](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/#Application_Directories) in iOS 8 with Xamarin?

Comment: Can you explain the downvote? E.g. giving an answer? Is there something like `var caches = Path.Combine (NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0].Path, "Caches");`?

Comment: No idea why there was a downvote, just voted your question up ;-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try:

```
var documents = NSFileManager.DefaultManager
    .GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User)[0].Path;

var tmp = Path.Combine(documents, "../", "tmp");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. One question though: Will this the real `tmp` directory or a subdirectory of the `Documents` directory (which can be made available to the user through iTunes file sharing and will be backed up)?

Comment: Interesting. He makes this path `/Documents/../tmp/test.jpg`. Through `..` he is in the correct path.

Comment: Was wondering about that strange path lately, too. For a detailed overview see http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/

Answer (score 6):

You can just use

```
var tmp = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath ();
```

This will return your app's tmp directory

Answer (score 1):

```
//https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system
public string TempPath()
{           
    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var ret = Path.Combine(documents, "..", "tmp");
    return ret;
}
```